# Build a Digital Plotter

Tags: code-golf

*Problem adapted from the book **[Fortran 77](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/FORTRAN-77-DONALD-M-MONRO-ARNOLD-PAPERBACK-BOOK-PRINTED-1987-/121637388292) by Donald M. Monro***

### Introduction

Digital plotting machines are widely used to produce various forms of drawings, graphs and other pictorial results. Most such machines can move their pens only in certain directions, usually as single steps in the X and Y direction or both. A typical machine would move in one of the eight directions shown in Fig. 1:

[image: Figure 1]
<sup>[Fig.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_fig) 1</sup>

### Challenge

Write a program *without trigonometric functions* which takes a number from 0 to 7 (inclusive) as input and outputs the corresponding coordinates of the endpoints in Fig. 1.

Output should as an array or list with two elements (i.e. `(1, 0)` or `[0,-1]`)

### Table of I/O

```
0 (1, 0)
1 (1, 1)
2 (0, 1)
3 (-1, 1)
4 (-1, 0)
5 (-1, -1)
6 (0, -1)
7 (1, -1)
```

### Winning

Shortest code in bytes wins

Comment: Does a `rotate(x)` function count as a trigonometric function? (it just rotates the "canvas" by `x` radians)

Comment: @Kritixi No, the restriction is solely on `cos, sin, tan, sec` etc.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's a related question that involves following the perimeter of a square of specified size but I can't find it.

Comment: <s>Can</s> May we 1 index instead of 0 index?

Comment: @Jonathan No, it must start at 0

Comment: Are you going to select the winner?

Comment: @2501 Sure, just let me get round to it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
Hı*µḞ,ĊṠ
```

Using complex arithmetic appears to be allowed.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@@9xZKPWoa0Pd8zTOdL1cOeC/wZF5oe2Ht1zuP1R0xpvIHb/DwA)

#### How it works

```
Hı*µḞ,ĊṠ  Main link. Argument: n

H         Halve; yield n/2.
 ı*       Yield i^(n/2), where i is the imaginary unit. Since i = e^(iπ/2), this
          computes e^(inπ/4) = cos(nπ/4) + i×sin(nπ/4) = x + iy, where (x, y) is
          the coordinate pair of (nπ/4)/(2π) = n/8 turns along the unit circle.
   µ      Begin a new chain with argument z = x + iy.
    Ḟ     Real part of z; yield x.
      Ċ   Imaginary part of z; yield y.
     ,    Pair, yielding (x, y).
       Ṡ  Apply the sign function to x and y.
```

Answer (score 15):

## Python 2, 29 bytes

```py
lambda n:1j**(n/2)*(1+n%2*1j)
```

Returns the coordinates as a complex number.

Comment: Oh nice. I didn't even think of using complex numbers!

Comment: Of course this does use trigonometric functions in a sense.

Comment: @ceasedtoturncounterclockwis Sure, but it simplifies the equation until they're no longer present.

Answer (score 7):

## Mathematica, 24 bytes

```
Sign@{12-8#+#^2,4#-#^2}&
```

Pure function, using `Sign` and knowing where certain parabolas go.

Answer (score 6):

## C, <s>103</s> <s>86</s> <s>74</s> <s>73</s> 70 bytes

*Thanks to @orlp for saving <s>12</s> 15 bytes!*

```
f(n){n="biM1*#?["[n]/7;printf("%c%d %d",n&8?32:45,n/4&1,n%2*~-(n&2));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#@5@mkadZnWerlJTpa6ilbB@tFJ0Xq29uXVCUmVeSpqGkmqyaoqCaoqSTp2Zhb2xkZWKqk6dvomaok6dqpFWnq5GnZqSpaV37H6haITcxM09Dk6uaSwEE0jQMNK0LSkuKNZSUNK1hYoZYxIywiBljETPBImaKRcwMi5g5kFn7HwA)

Comment: `"\16\17\13\7\6\5\9\15"[n] == "pw[1*#?i"[n]/7`

Comment: @orlp Thanks! Though the string is actually `"biM1*#?["`, because in `"\16\17\13\7\6\5\9\15"` the values are octal numbers, so 16 == 14 in decimal, 17 == 15 and so on.

Comment: `!!(n&4) == n/4&1`

Comment: `n&2?n&1:-(n&1) == n%2*~-(n&2)`

Comment: [68 bytes](https://tio.run/##bcrRCoIwGIbhc69iLBb7xZFOy2BmV9AVSAc2mQz0R9KOxC69tQ4623f08vBp0WvtnOEIK17ow96yeHdtaIP3Q6mmp8XFcMpkR1hHE8GxquS5rvMUmEyQyfjtbS8B1Ob8l4ytRQ7RGpHfDE9BTa9l5pSC@lsWMBmwPGBFwI4BOwWs9Lm5jzZD289ODOMX "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 5):

## [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator), 33 bytes

```
f(n)=mod(floor([4,2]^55/3^n),3)-1
```

[Try it on Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gvur2d5a0f)

The coordinate is returned as a 2 element list.

Comment: Yo welcome to code golf!! You are from the Desmos Discord, right?

Comment: @AidenChow thanks, yeah!

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>41</s> 36 bytes

```
r=>[1-(6800>>r*2&3),(425>>r*2&3)-1]
```

Uses two simple lookup tables which encode the 8 entries in base 4 after adding one to each "digit". Alternate version, using simpler lookup tables:

```
r=>["22100012"[r]-1,"12221000"[r]-1]
```

---

Old version (4 bytes shorter thanks to @Neil):

```
r=>[r>2&r<6?-1:r<2|r>6,r>4?-1:r%4&&1]
```

Naive approach using some simple calculations to find the X and Y coordinates separately...

Comment: Your current version gives incorrect answers for 4 and 5 but I think either `r&&(r<4)-(r>4)` or `r%4&&1-(r&4)/2` save a byte on your old version.

Comment: @Neil Hmm, I don't think that's an easy fix so I'll just switch to an alternate version. Thanks for the other tip though :-) It looks golfable, but I don't see how...

Comment: I think I've shaved a bit more off, still not quite short enough yet though: `r=>[r>2&r<6?-1:r<2|r>6,r>4?-1:r%4&&1]`

Comment: You can save a byte with `n=>[(s='22100012')[n]-1,s[n+6&7]-1]`.

Answer (score 4):

## APL, 21 bytes

```
{×¯4 4+1 ¯1×2*⍨⍵-4 2}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf!

Answer (score 3):

## TI-Basic, 23 bytes

```
Prompt X
e^(i(pi)X/4
round({real(Ans),imag(Ans)},0
```

Assumes your calculator is in radian mode; if that needs to be in the program, then it's 25 bytes.

Comment: I think radian mode is on by default, so you should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>13</s> 12 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

*I am still fairly confident there is shorter, but I have not found anything yet, so thought I'd post this*

```
+2,ị6400b3¤’
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@69tpPNwd7eZiYFBkvGhJY8aZv7//98EAA)** or see a [test suite](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@69tpPNwd7eZiYFBkvGhJY8aZv4/3P6oac3//9EGOoY6RjrGOiY6pjpmOuaxAA)

#### How?

```
+2,ị6400b3¤’ - Main link: n                        e.g. 7
+2           - n+2                                      9
  ,          - paired with n: [n+2,n]                   [9,7]
          ¤  - nilad followed by link(s) as a nilad      9th         7th
    6400     -     6400                                  v           v
        b3   -     to base 3: [2,2,2,1,0,0,0,1]         [2,2,2,1,0,0,0,1]
   ị         - index into (1-indexed and modular)       [2,0]
           ’ - decrement (vectorises)                   [1,-1]
```

---

An [alternative method](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@x@vr6Ot/3DnAi4jp8Ptjxp3HFr4//9/EwA), also **12 bytes**:

```
_/,+/Ṡ  - Link 1: get next coordinate: current coordinate (list) e.g. [-1,-1]
_/      - reduce by subtraction                                       0
   +/   - reduce by addition                                         -2
  ,     - pair                                                        [0,-2]
     Ṡ  - sign (vectorises)                                           [0,-1]

2BÇ⁸¡ - Main link: n
2B    - 2 in binary: [1,0]
    ¡ - repeat
   ⁸  - left argument (n) times:
  Ç   -     last link (1) as a monad
```

Answer (score 1):

## C, 66 bytes

```
f(n){printf("%d %d\n",(n-2)%4?n>2&n<6?-1:1:0,(n-4)%4?n>4?-1:1:0);}
```

test code

```
main(i)
{for(i=0;i<8;++i) f(i);}
```

results

```
1 0
1 1
0 1
-1 1
-1 0
-1 -1
0 -1
1 -1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 34 bytes

```javascript
e=>[434,5].map(n=>(85*n>>2*e&3)-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc6xDsIgFIXh3acgHcylgQYKtC7wIsaBVGo0FRprfH3MpZOR@cufcx7@47fpdV/fPKZryLPNwbqzVpqZS/f0K0Tr4GTa6FzfhqOiXNI8pbilJXRLusEMgjLSCAKSEUEbevhViSqLyn/tUXsCoqoKVRHg9Vgj650rywbZ7Mwr@YA@lO0aj8hjOV44fwE)

Answer (score 0):

### C, 56 bytes

```
d(n){printf("%d,%d",n+2&3?n+2&4?-1:1:0,n&3?n&4?-1:1:0);}
```

Simple binary search done twice. The first search is done on n shifted by 2.

[Online output on Ideone.](https://ideone.com/3Epp5s)

### C, 53 bytes

```
r;p(n){r?0:p(r=n+2);r=!printf("%d ",n&3?n&4?-1:1:0);}
```

Output without a comma was able to be compacted even more using a recursive call.

[Online output on Ideone.](https://ideone.com/UoR0of)